# How to replace Inf and NaN with NA in an xts object

Tags: r, xts

I have an `xts` object (`df`):

```
##                  a     b
## 2015-09-14 -0.5470    NA
## 2015-09-15  0.0112    NA
## 2015-09-16  0.0910 0.932
## 2015-09-17    -Inf 0.862
## 2015-09-18     Inf 1.946
## 2015-09-21 -0.7050 2.692
## 2015-09-22     NaN 2.011
## 2015-09-23 -0.5440 1.859
##     .
##     .
##    etc
```

Because column `a` includes `Inf`, `-Inf` and `NaN`, I am getting some errors. Is there a way to replace these values with `NA` (to treat `Inf` and `NaN` as missing values)?

Comment: We like reproducible examples. But try `apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(is.finite(x), x, NA))`.

Comment: It replaces every values as NA.. I dont know whether it matters but some of the values in my datatsets are double/float (eg:   0.316552626)

Comment: It works fine given the data in your post - see my answer below. If it's not working for you, then you probably need to provide a data set that will reproduce your problems.

Comment: `df[is.infinite(df)|is.nan(df)] <- NA`

Comment: @user20650 - that seems to only work when the non-finite values are in the first column. e.g. try it with `df <- df[, 2:1]`.

Comment: @user20650 - are you testing on an `xts` object?

Comment: @user20650 - yep, all working okay again - something weird was going on with my R session I guess. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @jbaums; good stuff, thought it might be something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply`, like you might on an ordinary `matrix`

Using the data that you provided:

```
d <- xts(read.zoo(text='date a     b
2015-09-14 -0.5470    NA
2015-09-15  0.0112    NA
2015-09-16  0.0910 0.932
2015-09-17    -Inf 0.862
2015-09-18     Inf 1.946
2015-09-21 -0.7050 2.692
2015-09-22     NaN 2.011
2015-09-23 -0.5440 1.859', header=T, index=1))

apply(d, 2, function(x) ifelse(is.finite(x), x, NA))

##                  a     b
## 2015-09-14 -0.5470    NA
## 2015-09-15  0.0112    NA
## 2015-09-16  0.0910 0.932
## 2015-09-17      NA 0.862
## 2015-09-18      NA 1.946
## 2015-09-21 -0.7050 2.692
## 2015-09-22      NA 2.011
## 2015-09-23 -0.5440 1.859
```

An alternative approach is to make the replacement by indexing the elements to keep (or remove)

```
d[!is.finite(d)] <- NA
```

Comment: it worked , initially i made some mistake in my code

Comment: You should *not* use `apply` on data.frames, because `apply` coerces its first argument to a matrix/array. So the mixed types that a data.frame may contain must be converted to a single type, which can cause unexpected issues. And xts/zoo objects are matrix, not data.frame.